# My search bar animation isn't animating properly

Tags: html, css

On my website, I'm trying to create an animation where if you float your mouse over the search icon, a text box would slide up underneath the icon like the example shown below.

[image: bar]

The problem with mine though is that when I float my mouse over the search icon, the text box instead pops out of nowhere and slides to the right instead of underneath.

[image: bar2]

Sometimes, it just spazzes out and goes left and right at a fast rate when I float over it.

I followed the example code at this [website](https://codepen.io/fghty/pen/poePyao?editors=1100) and copied it but it isn't animating properly . I even tried to tweak it such as changing the name of the element to moving the position but it still isn't doing it correctly. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```css
form {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 1s;
  background: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  padding: 10px;
}
.search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42.5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
.fa {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 42.5px;
  height: 42.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #05050a;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

form:hover {
  width: 300px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-right: -100px;
}

form:hover .search {
  display: block;
}

form:hover .fa {
  background: #ffffff;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
   <input class="search" type = "search" />
   <i class="fa">
      <img src = {search} alt = "Search" width="22" height="22"></img> 
   </i>                    
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input-container {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  color: white;
}

.search {
  transition: all 1s;
  height: 42.5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 42.5px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.fa {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 42.5px;
  height: 42.5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #05050a;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.input-container:hover .search {
  width: 300px;
    color: black;
}

.input-container:hover .fa {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<form action="">
  <div class="input-container">
    <input class="search" type="search" />
    <i class="fa fa-search">
   </i>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I had to adjust the position of the circle as it was off center, but other than that, thank you. It's working now